# Sleep deprivation relation to growth rate and mental health in adolescence

Tags: human-biology, circadian-rhythms, chronobiology

Do sleep deprivation and its timing affect growth rate and mental health in adolescents? If so how much sleep is enough for teenagers?

---

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. I am afraid that personal medical questions and health advice are off-topic here, and your question would seem to be asking for health advice. Please see the [Help Centre](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @David i still think if Daulet reformulate this question as question with general meaning, I ll be able to answer this question.

Comment: @L.Diago — Then you need to explain to him how you think his question needs reformulating. My own opinion stands. If there is any SE site this is relevant to it would be Medical Sciences, but, like this site, that is supposed to be for professionals and serious students.

Comment: @L.Diago — I noticed that the poster used the "health" tag. The summary of that is worth reading: "Health and medicine questions are off-topic unless dealing with the biology underlying health and medicine. Please carefully explore the tour, help centre, and meta before posting health and medicine questions. Health is a physiological state of well-being referring to the (ab)normality of the cellular or organismal physiology."

Comment: @David but it can be take from circadian physiology point of view. Sleep deprivation And mental health Is pretty common topic in chronobiology.

Comment: @L.Diago — Well make and state your assumption of what a good question would be and give a good technical answer. My vote is only one of five needed to close a question.

Comment: @L.Diago Thank you very much for editing my question! : -)

Comment: @Daulet Aybaz i ll try produce relevant answer as soon as possible.

Comment: @L.Diago I would appreciate it!

Comment: @DauletAybaz i am sorry that it is taking so long, but i was really surprice about lack of articles on growth hormone regulation associated with sleep. Just saying that i wont ditch you.

Comment: @L.Diago Thank you for your work! I really appreciate it and waiting for your answer and info)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of papers (from the same group, it seems) defines sleep deprivation in adolescents as [less than 6hr of sleep within a month](https://sci-hub.tw/10.1016/j.adolescence.2009.03.007). They found that sleep deprivation increases health risks, importantly [depression](https://watermark.silverchair.com/aasm.37.2.239.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAmEwggJdBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggJOMIICSgIBADCCAkMGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMC71TQOeWAqM2wOHUAgEQgIICFE01wnxZuBpySh3aVbW81Rix1_9uUvgP_8tTEmReVEJ5Y_UjcRjSLr8LfX4IYYWdNSVYN6l8Ar1VSbm3WLMu_XXGj9T4Iiino8KiOyw4e-q3CfmEVdhofhoW0GkGo8mSjBjPiOm5TZIwwlcVsWsbt0EAYLqrUELz6fbQYLz37FCPXFGBwFFiYuNEEDkHgP_wKf7ieLGn3VTMLdatf29tyNE65iw7-fNvJDDN9B3crnBMcbGsfr8I7OkErcERjUz24JyVdxg6BgmGzpBb3bU-yWjhFSF4ZH_d10gseqtSh-dzlTUIiIoyn8Ym96M1aItdCD1lBCcX5Lgv6-YJJpDELGTNH6Dl_K_9Pz-qjmxcM8qWZt3M5_xjG_guqnL-ArevXYj1EQ7XLKfCH5d_P_5NiTVL-InjttPNmsf46HV-Hh4DVT2KzDIhDBnjCG3lI4BXJDXpsXKp0HRM4qGpTgrEOrmxKGTHsiAYjxeq5ORVhOLbwqZoT2iSRGAP5qPbgupDCPxTsLUAeqNNtwaskl1dVTtCu9apkK1s_tDUaUHDuOOnPSHjjtMSYlQpl7TuPzkiKOW6DkI5kQPUCo56yewy72D8GzYhprjbZvy4Z-mf1ADByX9Fpb9Ohp0SnVEp_OeLwVpeX0SOPF9K0NI7raa5qhAmq5lxoLD_bMXgdEuMq3WEfWZDDZ36mrMf2t8DyxDKjQ9NrRo) (which in turns increases sleep deprivation).

Comment: I think it needs to be pointed out, that defining sleep deprivation as less than 6hr and finding some detrimental effects says absolutely nothing about whether more than 6hr is enough.